# IPFS not storing encrypted file completely

Tags: django, encryption, ipfs

I am using `django-ipfs-storage` module for my project and wants to upload a file to `InterPlanetaryFileSystemStorage()` model field. However if I simply upload a pdf file, it gets successfully uploaded but when I upload after encrypting the file, only first 4096 bytes are stored and rest are not there.
When I tried adding the same encrypted file using `ipfs add` command on the terminal, the file is successfully uploaded. Here is the code for uploading an encrypted file:

```
file_ = open(os.path.join(settings.ENCRYPTION_ROOT,str(paper)+'.encrypted'),'rb')
s_file = File(file_)
store = Request.objects.get(tusername=request.user.username)
store.paper.save(str(paper)+'.encrypted',s_file,save=True)
```

I have searched everywhere but still didn't get any help in this regard.